# How to refer to OLE Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

In one of my worksheets I have another workbook inserted as an embedded object, which I need to open to read some of its fields.

I open this file using *OLEobj.Verb xlVerbOpen*, and assign it to a *Workbook* variable called *wbR*. Because its name may change each time it is opened, the only way I have figured to do so is using *ActiveWorkbook*.

This works when I run the code line by line. However when the whole macro is run from a button, most of the time *ActiveWorkbook* will be considered the same as *ThisWorkBook*. I tried using Wait and Sleep.

The part giving this problem:

```
For Each OLEobj In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").OLEObjects
    Set OLEobj = wsr.OLEObjects(OLEobj.Name)
    OLEobj.Verb xlVerbOpen
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    'Sleep 5000
    Set wbR = ActiveWorkbook
    Exit For
Next OLEobj
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `.Verb xlVerbOpen` can be dicey to get the "active" application.

`Activate (start/open)` the object and use the `OLEFormat.Object.Object` to get the workbook object.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim wb As Object

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet where the excel file is embedded
    Set ws = Sheet1

    '~~> Change this to the relevant object name
    Set shp = ws.Shapes("Object 1") ' OLEobj.Name? from your code?

    '~~> Activate it (Open it)
    shp.OLEFormat.Activate

    '~~> Get the workbook object
    Set wb = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object

    With wb
        '
        '~~> Work with the workbook object here
        '

        MsgBox .Worksheets.Count
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your suggestion I have changed my code as seen below and it does work as a charm. Thank you so much for your help!!

```
For Each OLEobj In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ratios").OLEObjects
    Set OLEobj = wsr.OLEObjects(OLEobj.Name)
    'OLEobj.Verb xlVerbOpen
    OLEobj.Activate
    **Set wbR = OLEobj.Object**  ' New line that solves the issue.
    Exit For
Next OLEobj
```